# Check if char isletter without special characters like á

Tags: c#, .net, char

i want to check if a string only contains correct letters.
I used `Char.IsLetter` for this.
My problem is, when there are chars like é or á they are also said to be correct letters, which shouldn't be.

is there a possibility to check a char as a correct letter A-Z or a-z without special-letters like á?

Comment: I have to export a file, and import it to another application which throws errors if there are special signs like é,...

Comment: Of course é or á are letters...

Comment: I don't know why they wouldn't be letters, but you could force them back to ascii, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2086575/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
bool IsEnglishLetter(char c)
{
    return (c>='A' && c<='Z') || (c>='a' && c<='z');
}
```

You can make this an extension method:

```
static bool IsEnglishLetter(this char c) ...
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use  `Char.IsLetter(c) && c < 128` .  Or just `c < 128` by itself, that seems to match your problem the closest.

But you are solving an **Encoding** issue by filtering chars. Do investigate what that other application understands exactly.

It could be that you should just be writing with `Encoding.GetEncoding(someCodePage)`.

Comment: c < 128 by itself will return non-letters

Answer (score 7):

You can use regular expression `\w` or `[a-zA-Z]` for it

Comment: I think the second is better, the first might accept accented characters, too.

Comment: not 100% sure, but as I remember it won't. I've had some trouble with that. \w won't match Norway's symbols for example. There is a way with enabling unicode: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I'm not sure either. Since we're both sure [a-zA-Z] will work, and so will anybody reading the code, it's better.

Answer (score 5):

#### Update in .NET 7

There is now a [`Char.IsAsciiLetter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/dotnet/api/system.char.isasciiletter?view=net-7.0) function which would exactly meet the requirements

Answer (score 3):

In `C# 9.0` you can use [pattern matching enhancements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements).

```
public static bool IsLetter(this char c) =>
    c is >= 'a' and <= 'z' or >= 'A' and <= 'Z';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Create the regular expression
string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z]+$";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

// Compare a string against the regular expression
return regex.IsMatch(stringToTest);
```

Answer (score -3):

Use **Linq** for easy access:

```
if (yourString.All(char.IsLetter))
{
    //just letters are accepted.
}
```

Comment: Eh? The OP explicitly pointed out that Char.IsLetter doesn't do what is needed.