# Convert a TimeSpan Formatstring to an InputMask

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I've got a `TimeSpan` with a custom format like `@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff"`, and want to use the `MaskedTextBox` from xceed (https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox&referringTitle=Home) to help the user to input a valid timespan.

Now I convert the `FormatString`-Property to an input mask like this

```
public string InputMask
{
  get
  {
    string mask = FormatString.Replace('h', '0');
    mask = mask.Replace('m', '0');
    mask = mask.Replace('s', '0');
    mask = mask.Replace('f', '0');
    mask = mask.Replace('d', '0');
    return mask;
  }
}
```

this solution looks ugly and not maintainable if the FormatString gets another format which I don't know yet. Is there a more elegant solution (e.g. with a regex replace), which replaces any letter with a `0`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975640/check-if-char-isletter) ? But I'd go with `for(int i = 0; i < mask.Length; i++) if(char.IsLetter(mask[i])) mask[i] = '0';`

Comment: this does not work because `mask[i]` has no setter, while strings are immutable.

Comment: Then i'd come to stackoverflow and post here my question =D

Comment: Any letter RegEx: `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
//using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string input = @"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff"; //i suppose it's FormatString in your case, don't know the MaskedTextBox
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "[a-zA-Z]","0");
```