# .net Dont allow Alphabet

Tags: .net

I need to check if my String contains Alphabet Characters.
Because it needs to just contains a number.

```
         String^ buffer;
         buffer = this->textBox4->Text;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I validate a string to only allow alphanumeric characters in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046740/how-can-i-validate-a-string-to-only-allow-alphanumeric-characters-in-it)

Comment: What did you try ? Posting irrelevant code doesn't help.

Comment: do the same thing as the linked question, but only for letters.

Comment: I got my String and I need to verifie if it got only numbers

Answer (score 0):

Look at the regular expressions provided by the [.NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), such as `^\d+^`. (Assuming whole numbers only).

Comment: @Amber: What framework are you using? `C#`, `VB.Net`, `C++.Net`, `F#` or something else?

Comment: @Amber: Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxwfbb3b.aspx) link. IF you combine it with the regular expression I provided, the code should yield `False` if the string is made from characters which are not numbers.