# Textbox Validation: Allow only alphabets and simple brackets "(" and ")" vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

I want to validate textbox with keyPress event. It should allow alphabets and "(" and ")" I have written code for alphabet check but don't know how to check for "(" and ")".

```
     Private Sub txtBankName_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtBankName.KeyPress
    If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        If Not ((Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 97 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 122) Or (Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 65 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 90) Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 32) Then
            e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows all Letters and "(" & ")". Refer to these two SO questions:
[How can I validate a string to only allow alphanumeric characters in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046740/how-can-i-validate-a-string-to-only-allow-alphanumeric-characters-in-it)
[Only allow specific characters in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607087/only-allow-specific-characters-in-textbox)

```
Private Sub txtBankName_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtBankName.KeyPress    
    If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "[^a-zA-Z0-9()\b]") Then
       e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @user3422209 I just converted my C# Code to VB.net. Its just a verbatim string literal. Try my updated code. Just removed "@".

Comment: Thank you so much.. but this accepts [ ] brackets too.. It shouldn't be accepted

Comment: @user3422209 There modified it. The string `"[^a-zA-Z0-9()\b]"` denotes the allowed strings to be typed. `\b` Allows backspace to delete characters.